# Some php codes in append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I need to append some php code, when user click in sample button, my code works properly, but I need do my job cleaner.
I've searched and I found out, I should be using jquery ajax for this,
but I don't know what should to do with ajax. I read some articles about jquery ajax, and I found some functions, like `$.ajax()`, `$.get()`, `$.post()`
but I dont know really what to do? can someone say me, what I should to do

```
button.live( 'click', function(){
    sample.append(<?phpcodes?>);
});
append(
   '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>'+
    '<?php foreach ( $terms as $term ){ echo '<option value="'. $term->slug .'">'. $term->name .'</option>'; } ?>'+
    '<?php echo __( "Sample","textDomain" ); ?>'+
    '<?php echo $example[0]['options']['0']['id']; ?>'+
    'and more ...'
);
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement ?

Comment: You cannot execute PHP code in the client browser, you'll have to add the form element in JavaScript

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i want to build a page builder wordpress metabox, i write my codes, and that work properly, but i want to do my job with jquery ajax, because my append() is about 120 lines codes

Comment: It is not possible to execute php code within `append` you can `echo` some string or use `json`.

Comment: @Tiger i want to use jquery ajax, its possible or should be use json? my append() function is about 120 lines code ( html + php , ... ).

Comment: This question is far too broad. An answer would involve a training course.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i dont know what i should to use? jquery ajax? or JSON? and how to use?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the PHP code in a separate .php file and call that file with JavaScript (ajax) when the user clicks the button. When the file is called the php functions in that file will execute.

Examlple HTML

```
<div id="mybutton">My button</div>
<div id="result">My result</div>
```

Example JavaScript

```
$( "#mybutton" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( "#result" ).load( "myphpcode.php", function() {
    });
});
```

Example myphpcode.php

```
<?php

    // Do your cleaning here

    echo 'Done cleaning!';

?>
```